# Función en Unity C# no quiere comparar una variable en algunas ocasiones

Tags: c#, unity

estoy en Unity con un error que no entiendo, esto es simplemente una función que busca el índice **int** en el que se halla un **string** en una **lista de strings**, devolviendo **-1 si no está** en lista.

El problema es que no devuelve el índice cuando debería, hay un momento en la ejecución que para un string de entrada devuelve el índice, pero otro momento en que no.

- No salen errores de sintaxis
- verificado los tipos de datos a comparar sean iguales
- cambiado los nombres de todas las variables por si acaso
- verificado que se imprime bien toda la lista de strings
- se imprime bien el string dado, confirmando que debe hallarse en la lista
- la función Equals ya la he modificado por simplemente == o por Compare, sin solución
- reemplazé la variable est en la comparación por el string literal buscado, y funciona
- creé un if de prueba antes del for, donde indago algo a la variable est, y no funciona, es como si no quisiera hacer operaciónes de comparación con esa variable, pero si la imprime
- repito que hay una parte del software donde se llama a la función y trabaja bien, en otras partes no, imprimiendo los datos de entrada y salida no debería haber percance, si "abc" == "abc" debería disparar el if...

```
    public int Est2Ind(string est)
    {
        Debug.Log(est);
        Debug.Log(".");
        for (int e = 0; e < estNombre.Count; e++)
        {
            Debug.Log(estNombre[e]);
            if (string.Equals(estNombre[e], est))
            {
                Debug.Log("si");
                return e;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("no");
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: El código se ve bien. ¿Estás seguro de que `estNombre` tiene el elemento que buscas?  Podría ayudar saber el resto del código de la clase.

Answer (score 1):

Resulta que el string tenía un carácter invisible **\r** y por eso a veces fallaba.

Lo estaba cargando desde un archivo de texto. Lo descubrí porque me mostraba menos caracteres de los que decía tener.

Comment: un clasico puedes usar est.trimp() para borrar el caracter